# random number between 0 - 8 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate 40 random numbers between 0 to 8

This is my code --

```
<body>
    <h1>This is a page for randomize number between 0 - 8 </h1> <br />

<button onclick="randomize()">Random number</button>

<p id="Output"></p>

<script>
function randomize() {

    var arr = []
while(arr.length < 40){
  var randomnumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)
  arr.push(randomnumber) 
}
document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = arr;
}
</script> 
</body>
```

I am expecting 40 random numbers to be Output like --

> ```
> 4
> 4
> 5
> 7
> 8
> 1
> 5
> 7
> ```

What I am doing wrong can someone correct me please and also I want the result to be outputted by the next line !

Can someone help !

Comment: What does your code output at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If you multiply by `8`, you are getting numbers from `0` to `7`.

b) `.innerHTML = arr.join('<br>')` should give you the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your code already works, just ad line breaks:

```html
<body>
<h1>This is a page for randomize number between 0 - 8 </h1> <br />

<button onclick="randomize()">Random number</button>

<p id="Output"></p>

<script>
function randomize() {

    var arr = []
    while(arr.length < 40){
        var randomnumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)) // 0-8 is 9 numbers
        arr.push(randomnumber) 
    }
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = arr.join('<br>'); // Add line break between numbers

}
</script> 
</body>
```

**EDIT: changed random multiplier from 8 to 9**

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look into your random calculation and use .join() to make the number in separate lines.

1) The random formulate should be `Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+High-Low))+Low;`. Since you multiply `Math.random()` with 8, you will only get 7 as maximum. However you're adding `+1` after random, you will still get 8 as maximum number but the minimum becomes 1. You're genearating **1 to 8** now.

2) If you need to echo each number in a new line, you need to join the array with `<br/>`. E.g. `document.getElementIdBy('Output').innerHtml = arr.join('<br/>')`.